# How to change menu by changing ng-show value (Angular js) in SPA apps

Tags: angularjs

I am developing a web chat apps having 2 menus in a SPA (Single Page Apps) using Node.js and Angular.js.

The default menu is the login page (enter email and password). Once the 2 details are entered and processed by the server (Node.js) ... the server will send string of either "PA" (for passed) or "FA" (for failed) back to the browser (client) through web socket.

Yes, all communication between browsers and the server (Node.js) are done  through web socket.

The pseudo code looks like below:

```
...

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

   <div ng-show="smpage == 0">
   <! This login menu will be displayed as a default page/menu>

   ...
   ...

   </div>

   <div ng-show="smpage == 1">
   <! This chat menu will be displayed upon getting string = "PA">

   ...
   ...
   </div>

<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>

   ...


   socket.on(`pushmessage`, function(data){ 

      if (data.text == "PA"){ 

         smpage = smpage + 1; //this supposed to increment the smpage value
      } 

      if (data.text == "FA"){ 
         if (smpage === 1)
         {
            smpage = smpage - 1; //this supposed to decrement the smpage value
         }
      } 


   var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
   app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.smpage = 0;
   });
</script>


</div>
```

My question is how do I INCREMENT the variable called smpage when string "PA" received at the browser hence the angular controller will hide the login menu and thus show the chat menu ?

Note: The smpage variable is normally incremented using ng-click as the following:

```
<button ng-click="smpage = smpage + 1">Click Me!</button>
```

Kindly help how do I programmatically do this smpage increment upon receiving the "PA" string/command from the server.

Thank you.

Comment: Try using https://github.com/btford/angular-socket-io

Answer (score 0):

You are integrating SOCKET.IO with AngularJS the wrong way.

Since this is not a part of your angular controller..

```
  socket.on(`pushmessage`, function(data){ 

  if (data.text == "PA"){ 

     smpage = smpage + 1; //this supposed to increment the smpage value
  } 

  if (data.text == "FA"){ 
     if (smpage === 1)
     {
        smpage = smpage - 1; //this supposed to decrement the smpage value
     }
  }
```

The `smpage` is not incremented within the controller scope.

Applying proper integration will yield to something similar to this:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope, socket) {
  $scope.smpage = 0;
  socket.on('pushmessage', function (data) {

      if (data.text == "PA"){ 
          $scope.smpage = $scope.smpage + 1; //this supposed to increment the smpage value
      } 

      if (data.text == "FA"){ 
         if ($scope.smpage === 1) {
            $scope.smpage = $scope.smpage - 1; //this supposed to decrement the smpage value
         }
      } 
  });
});
```

Please refer to [Writing an AngularJS App with Socket.IO](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/frameworks/angular-websockets/).

Comment: Thank you for the answer.... appreciate your kindness. I am new to Node and Angular, however Angular was added at later stage to perform SPA with 2 or more menus. The actual (earlier) codes contain Node + Bootstrap + websocket only. Upon adding Angular ... doing socket became a bit tricky for beginner like me. Thank you for your help.

Comment: No problem. The thing with angular is that the controller can only access variables declared in its scope. You have to be wary about that. Also, frameworks should be the 1st thing to consider when making a project and not the otherway around since it has a huge impact on extensibility. :)